# Return value in if condition using ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, if-statement, max

I have the following block of code:

```
      <div className="max">
        {Math.max.apply(
          Math,
          items.feeds.map(function(o) {
            const temp = 34;

            if(o.field1 <= temp) {
              return <b>{o.field1}</b>; //return NaN
             }
            else {
               return o.field1;
            }

          })
        )}
      </div>
```

However, the if statement returns NaN. If I just return o.field1, it works. Like this:

`items.feeds.map (function (o) {return o.field1}`

Is there an issue in my if statement? I want if the value of o.field1 satisfies the condition when printing to screen it is bold.

Comment: Use filter instead

Answer (score 1):

`Math.max` returns a number:

> Return value: The largest of the given numbers. If at least one of the
>   arguments cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.

What you return is `<b>{o.field1}</b>` - it cannot be converted to a number. Wrap returned number with `<b>` tags later.